How do you do a LEFT JOIN on an UPDATE in Bigquery?
So I noticed that in SQL Server the Update statement works differently than in Bigquery, for example, in SQL Server we can do:
UPDATE table1
SET table1.some_column = table2.some_column
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.some_value = table2.some_value
WHERE...

But the problem is that moving this to Bigquery update you can't just replicate like that because from my understanding the UPDATE will automatically do an INNER JOIN between the table to be updated and the table on the FROM clause so you can't have the same thing where you just want to do a LEFT JOIN. For example if you just want to do an INNER JOIN in Bigquery you can simply do:
UPDATE table1
SET table1.some_column = table2.some_column
FROM table2
WHERE table1.some_value = table.some_value

But what if I need to do a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN? I'm using Dataform to build my Bigquery tables.

If you are using big-query, why tag SQL Server? Which is a completely different database engine?

When you consulted the documentation, how did it suggest you solve this problem?

Documentation has no LEFT JOIN examples, otherwise I would've fixed it @DaleK

What happens when you try the sql server syntax?

The documentation suggests a sub-query approach... have you tried that?

I did tried that but it doesn't work since you have to use a FROM ( SELECT...) and in Bigquery it automatically assumes that FROM is an INNER JOIN and that is weird, so i basically have the LEFT JOIN on a subquery but then the FROM will INNER JOIN the result. @DaleK

And I don't have a unique key so the FROM clause will do an INNER JOIN and the result will be "UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row"

Can you illustrate with some simple data/examples what the distinction would be?  For example, if table1 has a key value (XXX) and table2 does not have a matching key value, what would you expect the resulting/final value of the updated table1 column to be?

The sub-query approach is where you use a sub-query to calculate the new column value, handles left join fine, because it will return null the same as a left join would

The FROM clause join can be a cross join if no condition is specified in the WHERE clause, otherwise it is an inner join. In either case, rows from the target table can join with at most one row from the FROM clause. Refer to this doc once  Gcp Doc.
As @bruno already mentioned in comment#3 , there is no gcp doc available for left join .However, you can raise a feature request for the same in the public issue tracker   and After creating the Fr on the Public issue tracker  ,You can vote for this feature by clicking the +1 and STAR mark to receive updates on it.
